Automating Admin Password Sync Between Keycloak Environments
I'm working with Keycloak and have encountered an issue while syncing data between production and staging environments. Here's the situation:
Architecture: Keycloak, mysql, backend (my code)

I take a database dump from the production instance I have (mysql) that is connected to Keycloak instance and restore it in the staging instance.
After the restoration, my backend cannot connect to the Keycloak server, receiving a 401 Unauthorized error.
To resolve this, I log in to the staging Keycloak admin console and manually update the admin user's password to match the staging environment's expected password.
Previously, I resolved a similar issue by deleting all admin users in the staging environment, which automatically created a new admin user with the correct password. However, this is not ideal for automation or long-term maintenance.
I tried using the keycloak-realm.json import feature, but it skips existing realms and doesn’t override them, so it’s not a viable solution for this case.

How can I automate the process of updating the admin user password (or resolving the 401 Unauthorized issue) when restoring a production Keycloak dump to staging, without manual intervention?
Keycloak version: 26.0.7
